# How to get Power BI's ODBC data source query to a dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, odbc, datasource

I have a Simba ODBC connected gateway from Big Query to Power BI, I wish to look out for lineage to my Power BI datasets, but all I get in the lineage page is a plain "ODBC connection" source, not the original query or BQ dataset originating the dataset.

Is it possible to achieve this? Basically, how do I track a Power BI dataset back to its Big Query dataset source?

I read Power BI's API documents, but the closest I got to the specific ODBC data source was just the name of the connection (DSN).